# How to prevent stackoverflow in my implementation QuickSort?

Tags: c, quicksort

I have problem with my QuickSort. When I try sort array of numbers in descending order my pointers don't go through the array, and my stack overflow. Maybe problem isn't in the pointers, but I don't see solution of this problem.

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
int Icmp(void* x, void* y);
bool SpecTest(int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*), int (*dcmp)(const void*, const void*));
int Dcmp(void* x, void* y);
void Quick_Sort(const void* ptr, int low, int high, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*));

int main(void)
{
    int (*cmp)(void* x, void* y) = Icmp;
    int (*dcp)(void* x, void* y) = Dcmp;
    assert(SpecTest(cmp, dcp));
    return 0;
}

bool SpecTest(int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*), int (*dcmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    typedef struct testArr {
        int* arr;
        size_t size;
    }testArr;
    testArr s3;//Back sorted array struct
    s3.size = 100;
    if ((s3.arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * s3.size)) == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s3.size; i++) {
        s3.arr[i] = s3.size - i;
    }
    my_qsort(s3.arr, s3.size, sizeof(s3.arr[0]), cmp);
    return checksortInt(s3.arr, s3.size, cmp);
}
int Icmp(void* x, void* y)
{
    return (*(int*)x > * (int*)y) - (*(int*)x < *(int*)y);
}

int Dcmp(void* x, void* y)
{
    return (*(double*)x > * (double*)y) - (*(double*)x < *(double*)y);
}

void Swapper(void* x, void* y, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char tmp = ((char*)x)[i];
        ((char*)x)[i] = ((char*)y)[i];
        ((char*)y)[i] = tmp;
    }
}

bool checksortInt(int* parray, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        if (parray[i] > parray[i + 1])
            return false;
    return true;
}

void my_qsort(const void* ptr, size_t count, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    Quick_Sort(ptr, 0, count - 1, size, cmp);
}

void Quick_Sort(const void* ptr, int low, int high, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    char* pivot = (char*)ptr + low * size;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (i < high && (cmp((char*)ptr + i * size, pivot) == -1))
            i++;
        while (j > low && cmp((char*)ptr + j * size, pivot) == 1)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            Swapper((char*)ptr + i * size, (char*)ptr + j * size, size);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (j > low)
        Quick_Sort(ptr, low, j, size, cmp);
    if (i < high)
        Quick_Sort(ptr, i, high, size, cmp);
}
```

Example:

Input[]: **Array of numbers in descending order**

Output[]: **Unhandled exception at 0x005D1889 in QuickSout.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x008A2F24).**

Comment: How big is the input?

Comment: @Ry Array of 100 int numbers.

Comment: This really should not overflow the stack (if run on some common PC platform). You are probably having some bugs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can see my code. What's wrong?

Comment: It's not easy to understand. Why is it different from the classical algorithms such as the pseudocode given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort ?

Comment: Please show how you actually call it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I added this in question.

Comment: Please have **one** self-contained code block that demonstrates the problem. Consider that an average reader wants to spend max 30 seconds to copy-paste, compile and run it

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I did it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Now, I guess, I did it.

Comment: It doens't compile. Missing comparison functions.

Comment: Have `Icmp` simply `return (*(int*)x > *(int*)y) - (*(int*)x < *(int*)y);`. Your `Quick_Sort` works -- there may be corner cases you need to address. Other than that, you have a signed/unsigned warning at `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {` -- just change `int` to `size_t` to address that. Your call to `Quick_Sort` must use `low = 0` and `high = n-1`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But my call already use that low=0 and high=n-1. No?

Comment: With `my_qsort(s3.arr, s3.size, ...` it seems that high will be n.

Comment: Try running through your code with an already sorted array. You will find that you missed an exit condition or two.

Comment: @SkivHisink I tested your code with `int a[] = { 9,3,6,1,0,5,7,2,8,4 };` and ascending and descending sorts -- no problems. I suspect you are off-by-one passing the `high` parameter.

Comment: If you are still having issues, the example I used was [QuickSort Overflow](https://paste.opensuse.org/90436635) For a descending sort, just flip the comparisons, e.g. `return (*(int*)x < *(int*)y) - (*(int*)x > *(int*)y);`

Comment: my_qsort() and checksortInt are undefined, it won't compile.

Comment: @rcgldr I added this functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to sort large arrays, and are concerned about worst case data patterns causing stack overflow, quicksort could recurse on the smaller partition and loop back for the larger partition, which will avoid stack overflow, but worst case time complexity will still be O(n^2).

```
void Quick_Sort(const void* ptr, int low, int high, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    int i;
    int j;
    char *pivot;
    while(low < high){
        i = low;
        j = high;
        pivot = (char*)ptr + ((low+high)/2) * size;
        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (cmp((char*)ptr + i * size, pivot) == -1)
                i++;
            while (cmp((char*)ptr + j * size, pivot) ==  1)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                Swapper((char*)ptr + i * size, (char*)ptr + j * size, size);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        if (j < low)                  // adjust so low <= j <= i <= high
            j = low;
        if (i > high)
            i = high;
        if(j - low <= high - i){
                Quick_Sort(ptr, low, j, size, cmp);
            low = j + 1;
        } else {
            if (i < high)
                Quick_Sort(ptr, i, high, size, cmp);
            high = i - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

---

This alternate version is a bit simpler.

```
void Quick_Sort(const void* ptr, int low, int high, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    int i;
    int j;
    char *pivot;
    while(low < high){
        i = low-1;
        j = high+1;
        pivot = (char*)ptr + ((low+high)/2) * size;
        while (1)
        {
            while (cmp((char*)ptr + ++i * size, pivot) == -1);
            while (cmp((char*)ptr + --j * size, pivot) ==  1);
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            Swapper((char*)ptr + i * size, (char*)ptr + j * size, size);
        }
        if(j - low <= high - j){
            Quick_Sort(ptr, low, j, size, cmp);
            low = j+1;
        } else {
            Quick_Sort(ptr, j+1, high, size, cmp);
            high = j;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternate version without the stack overflow prevention:

```
void Quick_Sort(const void* ptr, int low, int high, size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    int i;
    int j;
    char *pivot;
    if(low >= high)
        return;
    i = low-1;
    j = high+1;
    pivot = (char*)ptr + ((low+high)/2) * size;
    while (1)
    {
        while (cmp((char*)ptr + ++i * size, pivot) == -1);
        while (cmp((char*)ptr + --j * size, pivot) ==  1);
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        Swapper((char*)ptr + i * size, (char*)ptr + j * size, size);
    }
    Quick_Sort(ptr, low, j, size, cmp);
    Quick_Sort(ptr, j+1, high, size, cmp);
}
```

Comment: I added the missing functions. Your function don't sort sorted array. I have waited for 7 minutes, but nothing happended(program work, but stay on this function)

Comment: @SkivHisink - I updated my answer. I normally use the second example above, which doesn't have the issue of i or j going past the ends of a sub-array.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. I solved the problem using random permutation of numbers in an array, but I think it's cheating.

Comment: @SkivHisink - for sorted or reverse sorted arrays, using `pivot = (char*)ptr + ((low+high)/2) * size;` will solve both space and time issues for those specific cases. The examples above handle worst case data patterns, which are actually rare, unless a worst case data pattern is deliberately created. I updated my answer.

Comment: @SkivHisink - I added a 3rd example without the stack overflow prevention, which is simpler. As for the original problem with only 100 elements to sort, I wasn't getting stack overflow with your original code, so I still don't know what that problem was. You might want to try sorting something like 5 to 20 million elements and compare the run times and/or see if there are stack overflow issues.